# Unhandled Error Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

I need some help regarding @capacitor-community/sqlite.
I'm using @capacitor-community/sqlite which works fine on a developer PC but on installing the app on a different computer, it raised an error saying `"**Unhandled Error Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file**"` when I tried to access/create a database.

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Fbk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, if the app was installed as All Users, then running the app as admin will get past the error (because the db is installed in the program files folder). Installing as single user does not have this issue, but the db should be in the users/Database folder and it is not.